# Rudin's definition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I want to ask one thing: Why does not Rudin define negative powers in the 1st chapter of baby Rudin? Or is $x^{-1}$ just defined as the inverse of $x$ as in a field ($1/x$ as it is given)?

Comment: Walter Rudin wrote several text books (the two most famous, **Principles of Mathematical Analysis** and **Introduction to Mathematical Analysis** are known as "Rudin" and "baby Rudin").  Which are you referring to?

Comment: Note:  **Principles** ="baby Rudin"

Comment: @user247327 I think Rudin's two most famous books are Principles of Mathematical Analysis ("baby Rudin") and Real & Complex Analysis.

Answer (score 0):

In exercise $1.6$, for $b>1$,

He defines $$b^x=\sup\left\{ b^t: t \in \mathbb{Q}, t \le x\right\}$$

for any real $x$, after he checks that rational exponent is well defined.

Comment: But in part a) he says $m>0$, $q>0$, so $m,n$ can be negative (which comes before part c).

Comment: hmm... you are right. good point. it seems that it has to be defined before that to make it well defined. I would believe it is the field multiplicative inverse then.